# Передать дженерик тип в перегруженый метод

Tags: java, generics, перегрузка-операторов

Есть следущий код с использованием дженериков.

```
public class Core<T> {
 public void pEntity() {
        Person person= new Person();
        T entity= new Something<T>().getE();
        ObjectSetter.setPersonId(entity,person);
    }
}
```

ObjectSetter имеет перегруженные методы.

```
   public static void setPersonId(Class1 cls1, Person person){
        cls1.setPersonId(person.getId());
    }
    public static void setPersonId(Class2 cls2, Person person){
        cls2.setIdPerson(person.getId());
    }
```

IDEA ругается на это

> Cannot resolve method 'setPersonId(T, model.Person)'

Полагаю надо использовать Instanceof, но перегрузка выглядит так удобно и лаконично.
Или я что то совсем напутал... помогите новичку, как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сможете использовать instanceOf, дженерик типы стираются после компиляции и в рантайме приложение не в состоянии определить входящий тип.

Если вы хотите перегрузить метод, то надо писать либо два дженерика под каждый из методов либо приводить все к одному методу который будет принимать какой-то интерфейс типа `<T extends YourInterface>` в котором будет нужный вам метод и уже в реализации каждого класса вы будете определять как его реализовать.